# Copy all the text in "File1" and replace it with a specific text in File 2 using sed command

Tags: bash, sed, github-actions

Let's say I have a file called `File1.txt` that has the string

```
Hamburger
```

And I have another file called `File2.txt` that has the string:

```
I love Pizza
```

I want to use the `sed` command to make changes such that it copies all the text from `File1.txt` i.e. `Hamburger` and replace it in `File2.txt` with the word `Pizza` so that the final output in `File2.txt` would be

```
I love Hamburger
```

Is there a way to do this suing the sed command ?

Here's an example of code I am trying to use but it doesn't work:

```
sed -e '/Hamburger/{r File1.txt' -e 'd}' File2.txt
```

Comment: From your example, I guess you mean in reality _and replace in File2.txt the word Pizza by it_ ...

Comment: Why do you **want** to use `sed`? The main problem with this approach is, that the replacement operator in `sed` needs a delimiter. While you can choose the delimiter yourself freely, it means that the content of  File1.txt must not contain this delimiter, and if you want to keep your solution generic (i.e. File1.txt can contain **any** text), this gets tricky.

Comment: You can sort of do it this way `sed -e $'/Pizza/{s/Pizza//;rFile1.txt\n;}' File2.txt`, (a shell supporting `$''` is required for this copy/paste friendly version) but sed does not make this easy.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I have edited my question with the code I was trying to use, I am not committed to sed I just have some experience with it I also have the liberty to use some other tools like awk and grep if possible.

Comment: Hi @sorpigal, I am trying to run it on GitHub Actions, I am not sure if it is supported there.

Comment: Your example sed command is nowhere near valid, I don't even know where to start.

Comment: You can't use sed for replacing a string inside a line with the content of a file, at least not directly: the `r` flag adds the content of the file a line BELOW the match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `sed`

```
$ sed "s/Pizza/$(cat File1.txt)/" File2.txt
I love Hamburger
```

Comment: You can replace `$(cat File1.txt)` with `$(< File1.txt)`, at least in bash

Answer (score 1):

The question is tagged `github-actions`, so I am going to make some guesses.

- You have a config file with some template data in it.
- You want to automatically replace that with some real data that is stored in another file.

There are many ways you could do this, but here's one using `envsubst`

First, rewrite your template `File2.txt` this way

```
I love $Pizza
```

Then run this shell script:

```
export Pizza=$(<File1.txt)
envsubst '$Pizza' < File2.txt
```

This will print out the phrase you expect by expanding `$Pizza` within the file to the content of the corresponding environment variable, but not expanding any other things that look like environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*/s#pizza#&#/' file2 | sed -f - file1
```

Turn file2 into a sed script and apply to file1.